# How to make a section/div of page behave as full page/parallax scroll but allow rest of the section to have normal browser/device scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, parallax

I am trying to achieve full page/parallax scroll only for one particular section of the page when it comes to view and allow the rest of the section to normal browser/device scroll behavior.

The challenge is, each section is a different component and can be placed in any order in the page. The special-section is the one which needs a full page/parallax scrolling effect.

I tried making the special-section position fixed when it is in viewport but the general user experience is choppy and fails in scenarios where the user is scrolling slowly.

HTML

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Scroll Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section"><span class="big-font">#1</span></div>
        <div class="section"><span class="big-font">#2</span></div>
        <div class="section"><span class="big-font">#3</span></div>
        <div class="section"><span class="big-font">#4</span></div>
        <div id="specialSection" class="section special-section">
            <div id="specialWrapper" class="special-wrapper">
                <div class="box">
                    #Box 1
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    #Box 2
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    #Box 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section"><span class="big-font">#5</span></div>
        <div class="section"><span class="big-font">#6</span></div>
        <div class="section"><span class="big-font">#7</span></div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</DOCTYPE>
```

CSS

```
.big-font {
    font-size: 36px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #353535;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.section {
    min-height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 30px;
}
.special-section {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #543333;
}
.in-view {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.special-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px dotted white;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

JS

```
    // Get the an HTML element
var element = document.getElementById('specialSection');
var specialElement = document.getElementById('specialWrapper');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

function isInViewport(element) {
    // Get the bounding client rectangle position in the viewport
    var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('Bounding Top : ', bounding.top);
    console.log('Bounding Bottom : ', bounding.bottom);
    console.log('Window Innerheight : ', window.innerHeight);
    // Checking part. Here the code checks if it's *fully* visible
    // Edit this part if you just want a partial visibility
    if ((bounding.top < window.innerHeight/2) && bounding.bottom > window.innerHeight) {
        console.log('In the viewport! :)');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('Not in the viewport. :(');
        return false;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (isInViewport(element)) {
        // update the element display
        body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
        element.classList.add('in-view');
        // element.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
        body.blur();
        specialElement.focus();
    }
}, false);

specialElement.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    const {scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight} = event.target;

    if (Math.abs(scrollHeight - clientHeight - scrollTop) < 5) {
        element.classList.remove('in-view');
        window.scrollBy(0, 200);
        specialElement.blur();
        // element.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        body.focus();
    }

    if (event.target.scrollTop < 5) {
        console.log('Elemt scroll top');
        element.classList.remove('in-view');
        specialElement.blur();
        body.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        // element.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        window.scrollBy(0, -200);
        body.focus();
    }

    }, false);
```

Comment: You added the tag `fullpage.js`, but... are you using the [fullPage.js library](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)?

Comment: Not using fullpage.js, removed the label @Alvaro